# Docker SDK: Look up a container's IP address?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, subprocess, docker-network

I have two Docker containers. Container One is named `5extraextranodes_plc1_1`, and is run with docker-compose on a bridge network named `test_net`.

Container 2 is built and run outside of docker-compose. In container 2, there is a Python3 script. Inside this Python3 script, I want to be able to look up the `5extraextranodes_plc1_1` container's IP address.

I originally tried to use `subprocess.checkout()` inside the Python code to run the `docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 5extraextranodes_plc1_1` command. But that gave me an error *FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker'*.

So now I am trying to do this using Docker SDK inside of my Python 3.6 script. I'm running the following code:

```
    client = docker.from_env()
    container = client.containers.list(filters={"name": "5extraextranodes_plc1_1"})
    ip_add = container.attrs['NetworkSettings']['IPAddress']
```

Unfortunately, this code gives me the error: *docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))* for the statement `client = docker.from_env()`.

How can I look up the `5extraextranodes_plc1_1` container's IP address from Container 2 on the same network?

**Note:** I am currently running Container 2 on the network `test_net` (same network as Container 1). I've also tried running it in network `host` mode. Both fail.

Comment: The easiest way to get the ip address of `5extraextranodes_plc1_1` is to attach your new container to the same network and then just use DNS.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a common network and Docker DNS like stated by @larsks:

By default containers are not allowed to change stuff on host system, this is a core concept of docker. But you're able to explicitly allow access to docker sock:

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock container2`

But keep in mind: This container gains superpower and should be secured very well if necessary.

If you have further problems please provide Dockerfile from container2